# Can Visual Studio Lightswitch connect to an oracle database?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-lightswitch

All the demos of [Visual Studio Lightswitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/default.aspx) use SQL-Server, it is possible to access data from Oracle using Visual Studio Lightswitch?

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59759/what-should-the-tag-for-visual-studio-lightswitch-be

Comment: Ian: I left an answer for you. You have three options (1) Oracle's ODP.Net 11.2 R4, (2) Third Party Drivers $$$, and (3) Open Source. @Matt Eisenberg was on the right track, but there's more options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio Lightswitch can be persisted to an Oracle Database via the Entity Framework.

1. **Oracle Data Provider (ODP.Net)**

   Oracle's ODAC Tools contains the Oracle Data Provider (ODP.Net) for use with Visual Studio applications. Oracle's latest driver with support for Entity Framework 4.1 and "Model First" approach.

   EDIT: I am not sure if it supports "Code-First" or EF 4.2 so check documentation. That said, *it's free and supported by Oracle so I would strongly suggest starting here before rolling your own, or using open source providers/drivers*.

   [Download ODP.Net 11.2.0.3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)

   [EF Tutorial w/ ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm)

   *Notes: "11.2.0.2 Release 4" will cut it, but "11.2.0.3 is" out and more stable.*
2. **Third party drivers are available for purchase:**

   [docConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/)

   [DevArt's ADO.Net Provider for Oracle](http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/index.html)
3. **Open Source Providers**

   In addition there are some open source options available - one I found on Github:

   https://github.com/object/NorthwindOData

---

Tutorial on [MSDN: How to Connect Lightswitch to EF 4.1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/lightswitchgeneral/thread/f128c587-9a85-4c68-bd9c-e2e8b1264838)

Comment: Is there every a version of the Oracle's ODAC Tools that is not in beta but does fully surport the shipping version of .net?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to edit my answer - 11.2.0.3 is is fully released, not beta... and it supports Entity Framework 4.1 - caveat: it supports "model first" and "4.1"... you'd have to read documentation or ask Support if 4.1 and Code-First approaches are good.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if you can get a third-part provider for the entity framework. I actually asked this question at VSLive this week.

Comment: how much do the third-part provider for the entity framework cost?  And does someone need to know how to program to hook it into Lightswitch?

Comment: http://web.datadirect.com/products/net/net-for-oracle/index.html. Not sure about the second part of your question.

Comment: As far the second part, I believe, that once it's installed on the person's machine, they just choose that as a data source.  They'll need to know connection information, just as if they were using any other data source.  But shouldn't need programming knowledge to hook it up.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the latest ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) that supports Entity Framework, and it works fine.

If you get this error, "Inner exception message: Connection is already part of a local or a distributed transaction"

you can resolve the issue by following the second post by BScholz, https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2263095

Basically, you need to implement SaveChanges_Excuting and SaveChanges_Excuted for the Oracle Data Source.

1. Switch to "File View" (LightSwitch will display "Logical View" by default).
2. Add a reference to "System.Transactions" in Server project.
3. Switch back to "Logical View"
4. Right Click the Data Source Name and click "View Code" to edit partial class.
5. Copy-and-paste the code below:

   ```
   private TransactionScope _tscope;

   partial void SaveChanges_Executing()
   {
       _tscope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
       new TransactionOptions
       {
           IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
       });
   }

   partial void SaveChanges_Executed()
   {
       _tscope.Complete();
       _tscope.Dispose();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The [LightSwitch training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=AC1D8EB5-AC8E-45D5-B1E3-EFB8E4E3EBD1) has an exercise dedicated to using alternative data sources via WCF RIA services.

You might find that useful.